# Restart PHP FPM as root - Authentication is required to restart 'php7.4-fpm.service'

Tags: ubuntu, php, debian, php-fpm

I have a www-data user, I allowed to restart PHP FPM by him in /etc/sudoers:

```
www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/usr/sbin/service php7.4-fpm restart
```

/etc/sudoers has right permissions

```
ls -la /etc/sudoers
-r--r----- 1 root root 915 Jan 19 23:26 /etc/sudoers
```

But I still can't restart FPM from www-data account

```
/usr/sbin/service php7.4-fpm restart
==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units ===
Authentication is required to restart 'php7.4-fpm.service'.
Authenticating as: root
Password:
```

When I'm trying to enter the password, I'm getting different error

```
polkit-agent-helper-1: pam_authenticate failed: Authentication failure
==== AUTHENTICATION FAILED ===
Failed to restart php7.4-fpm.service: Access denied
```

What can be wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `sudo` in order to make use of sudoers. It looks like you're just running `/usr/sbin/service php7.4-fpm restart`, try `sudo /usr/sbin/service php7.4-fpm restart` instead.

Comment: yes, it was simple, thanks.
but it still asks password when I try to restart.

sudo /usr/sbin/service php7.4-fpm restart

[sudo] password for www-data: 

how can I get rid of this? as you can see, I have NOPASSWD instruction